# how to insert the html url input form into python?

Tags: html, python-3.x, url, web-scraping

I am working on web scraping project and I am new in python but I have a problem about how to insert/get the user url input form and insert it into python script to scrape this input url and display the data back to the html file

I tried alot of ways with days but still nothing.

here is the code (html):

```html
<form method="get" onsubmit="return formsubmit();" action="test2.py">
     <input type="url" name="asin" id="asin" class="input-text" placeholder="Enter your link here e.g. (https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B064GWQXUJ1/)">
</form>
```

test.py:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

URL = "https://www.amazon.com/" 
# This URL I need it dynamically as per user input in the html file

res = requests.get(URL, headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")

price = soup.select_one("#priceblock_ourprice").text
size = soup.select_one("#dropdown_selected_size_name .a-dropdown-prompt").text    
color = soup.select_one("#dropdown_selected_color_name .a-dropdown-prompt").text
shipping_weight = soup.select_one("#productDetails_detailBullets_sections1 tr:nth-child(3) td").text
title = soup.select_one("#productTitle").text.split()

# I need to display the results into the html file with all these details 
print(price)
print(size)
print(color)
print(shipping_weight)
print(title)
```

Any help please ?

Comment: any help for my question??

Comment: Since you want to collect info from a web form, you need to build up a server. Have a look at `Flask`